# Invalid endpoint on aws s3 ls

Tags: aws-cli

I've just installed AWS Command Line Interface on Windows 10 (64-bit).  I ran 'aws configure' providing the two keys, a region value of us-east-1, and took the default json format.  Then when I run 'aws s3 ls' I get the following error:

Invalid endpoint:  https://s3..amazonaws.com

It's either not taking my region, or putting two dots where there should be one in the link.  My /.aws/config file only has these lines in it:

[default]

region = us-east-1

Any ideas why I get 2 dots in place of my region in the s3 link, causing the invalid endpoint error?   Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 7):

You could also fix this by setting environment variables in your current session for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

(in this case your error is actually caused by the CLI not finding a value for the region)

Answer (score 3):

I think that's not because of the region  because you have already set default to **us-east-1** as shown by your **/.aws/config** file but your output type is not set and double check your **access key id** and **secret access key**

it should be like:

[image]

[image]

also check whether you are able to call other AWS API services such as try to create a dynamodb table using AWS CLI and check whether your IAM user have access permissions to s3 or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you set AWS_DEFAULT_REGION in your any of `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

1. Remove AWS_DEFAULT_REGION in any of those files.
2. ~/.aws/config should be like this

   [default]

   output = json

   region = eu-west-1
3. Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just specify the region on the command line itself like below if you didn't want to rely on the default settings in the `~/.aws/config` file...

```
aws --region us-east-1 s3 cp s3://<bucket> <local destination>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was using [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) and was forgetting to prepend the command with:

`aws-vault exec {profile_name} -- {command_to_execute}`

For example:

`aws-vault exec MyProfile -- aws s3 ls`